# yarn install fails in docker build but succeeds when run in container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I'm unable to get **yarn install** to work when executed in Dockerfile by **docker build** but it works when run from command line within the container.

Dockerfile (most of relevant bits)

```
FROM ruby:2.7.6
RUN wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg
RUN cat pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN rm pubkey.gpg
...
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN --mount=type=ssh bundle install --without staging production \
  && find /usr/local/bundle/cache -name "*.gem" -delete \
  && find /usr/local/bundle/gems -name "*.c" -delete \
  && find /usr/local/bundle/gems -name "*.o" -delete
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker build** errors out with:

```
 ...
 => ERROR [14/15] RUN yarn install                                                                                                     3.2s
------
 > [14/15] RUN yarn install:
#0 0.459 yarn install v1.22.19
#0 0.471 info No lockfile found.
#0 0.475 [1/5] Validating package.json...
#0 0.478 [2/5] Resolving packages...
#0 3.184 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myrepo%2fmy-package: Not found".
#0 3.184 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/myapp/yarn-error.log".
#0 3.184 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install]: exit code: 1
```

But if I comment out (remove) **RUN yarn install** and the 3 lines after it at end of the **Dockerfile** then I'm able to successfully build an image that I can `docker compose run app bash` to enter a shell in the container where `yarn install` completes (probably because it's not trying to encode `/` in the url to `%2f` but who knows.

Thoughts? I'm stumped.

Comment: Worked brilliantly and `docker compose build` finished so quickly I thought I had left last lines commented out! If you submit this as an answer I can give you credit. This may be a workaround as it doesn't address why the `/` in URL for package name was being encoded `@myrepo%2fmy-package` in the first place but this bypasses trying to install it so I'm moving on…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a container I've always used

```
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install yarn && apt-mark hold yarn
```

so just replace

```
RUN yarn install
```

with

```
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install yarn && apt-mark hold yarn
```